# Transformar una respuesta Http Angular 12

Tags: angular

Hola estoy intentando obtener una respuesta http de mi Api  consultada desde un ID, donde devuelve un JSON  llamado `estatal` con la informacion de la consulta. En la misma respuesta tambien devuelve un array  llamado `archivos` donde vienen los archivos que le pertenencen a ese ID json.

Mi problema está en cómo transformar la respuesta, para que se me muestre toda la respuesta junta en la tabla del HTML.

**Respuesta del Api**
Aqui se muestra la respuesta del api consultada desde un ID, a donde devuelve un json y un array, el array y json

```
{
  "estatal": {
    "id": 3,
    "articulo": 15,
    "fraccion": "III",
    "nombre": "\tFacultades de Área",
    "descripcion": "Las facultades de cada Área.",
    "created_at": "2017-12-08T14:00:41.000000Z"
  },
  "archivos": [
    {
      "id": 938,
      "IdTransparencia": 3,
      "nombre": "MANUAL ",
      "descripcion": "MANUAL 2018",
      "archivo": "127.0.0.1:8000/storage/transparencia/15/3/MANUAL prueba2018.pdf",
      "art": 15,
      "anio": 2018,
      "activo": 1,
      "created_at": "2019-08-29 10:13:53"
    },
{
      "id": 939,
      "IdTransparencia": 3,
      "nombre": "operancion",
      "descripcion": "2018",
      "archivo": "127.0.0.1:8000/storage/transparencia/15/3/prueba2018.pdf",
      "art": 15,
      "anio": 2018,
      "activo": 1,
      "created_at": "2019-08-29 10:13:54"
    }
   
  ]
}
```

**html**

```
<div *ngIf="!estatal; else divPais"
class="alert alert-info">
  ESPERE POR FAVOR....
</div>

<ng-template #divPais>
<div id="conocenos">
  <div class="container-md">

      <div class="row pt-3">
          <h2 class=" pb-2 pt-2"> Fracción {{estatal.fraccion}} - {{estatal.nombre}}
          </h2>
          <hr>
         </div>

      <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="card w-100 card-border mb-5">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="card-text">
                  <p> 
                    {{estatal.descripcion}}
            
                  </p>

          <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Actualizado</th>
                    <th>Documentos</th>             
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
       <tbody>
                            <td><i>{{ archivo.nombre }}</i></td>
                            <td><i>{{archivo.descripcion }}</i></td>
                            <td><i>{{archivo.created_at}}</i></td>
                            <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" title="Visualizar" 
                         href="{{ archivo.archivo }}"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-file fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" title="Descargar" 
                      href="{{ archivo.archivo }}">
                   <i class="fa fa-download fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </td>

</tbody>

         </table>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

</ng-template>
```

**Interface.ts**

```
 
export interface TransparenciaNacional {
    id?:          number;
    articulo:    number;
    fraccion:    string;
    nombre:      string;
    descripcion: string;
    created_at?:  Date;
}

export interface PNacional {
    id?:          number;
    articulo:    number;
    fraccion:    string;
    nombre:      string;
    descripcion: string;
    created_at?:  Date;
}
```

**Component.ts**

En el componente uso un switchMap para pasarle el ID, en este caso es la respuesta de la API

```
  estatal!: TransparenciaNacional;
  constructor(  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private estatalService: TransparenciaEstatalService, ) 
    { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
            this.activatedRoute.params
            .pipe(
            switchMap( ({ id }) => this.estatalService.getEstatalById( id )),
            tap( console.log )
            )
            .subscribe( estatal => this.estatal = estatal);

  }
```

**SERVICIO**

```
 private url: string = environment.urlEndPoint;
  //private apiurl: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';
  
  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
 getNacionalById(id: number):Observable<TransparenciaNacional> {
    const urlapi = `${ this.url}transparenciaNacional/${id}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<TransparenciaNacional>(urlapi);

  }
```

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta?? Parece que ya tienes el servicio y el componente bien montados. Solo te faltaría un `ngFor` en el html para recorrer el array, algo así como `*ngFor let archivo of trans.archivos`. Eso si, tendrás que añadir el campo `archivos` a tu objeto TransparenciaNacional... por algún motivo no lo tienes, pese a que en la response dices que si recibes dicho array. Por cierto, no te devuelven un json y un array... te devuelven un json que contiene un json y un array. Los objetos json pueden perfectamente llevar un array dentro, como en este caso!

Comment: Mi problema esta, que a la hora de recorrer el ngfor, en la tabla no se visualiza nada, mi duda es como transformar la respuesta en el *ngOnInit*  para que me mande a llamar archivos

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo resolvi de la siguiente manera...

Component.ts

```
public estatal: any;
  public archivos: any;
  public titulo: string = '';
  public desripcion: string = '';

 
  constructor(  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private estatalService: TransparenciaEstatalService, ) 
    { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  

        this.activatedRoute.params
        .pipe(
        switchMap( ({ id }) => this.estatalService.getEstatalById( id )),
        tap( console.log )
        )
        .subscribe( estatal => { 
          this.estatal = estatal;
          this.titulo = this.estatal.estatal.fraccion + "-" + this.estatal.estatal.nombre;
          this.desripcion = this.estatal.estatal.descripcion;
          this.archivos = this.estatal.archivos;
            }

         );   
  }
```

En el html con un ngfor lo recorrí en array

```
   <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let item of archivos">
                  <td><i>{{item.nombre }}</i></td>
                  <td><i>{{item.descripcion }}</i></td>
                  <td><i>{{item.created_at}}</i></td>
                  <td><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" title="Visualizar" 
                        href="{{ item.archivo }}"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-file fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
```